# chrome extension not retrieving local files with chrome.extension.getURL?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getURL' of undefined`

**script.js**

```
var app = {
    init: function() {        
        var c = document.createElement("img");
        c.src = chrome.extension.getURL("logo.png");
        document.body.appendChild(c);
    }
}
app.init();
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "my extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {        
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "css": ["style.css"],
            "js": ["contentScripts.js"]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "script.js",
        "logo.png"
    ],
    "permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

**contentScripts.js**

```
var a = document.createElement("script");
    a.src = chrome.extension.getURL("script.js");
var b = document.createElement("style");
    b.src = chrome.extension.getURL("style.css");

(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(a);
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(b);
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Other posts on SO indicate that the local file must be included in your `manifest.json`. The javascript I am injecting works fine, but the `chrome.extension.getURL` method doesn't seem to be working?

Answer (score -1):

The script is running in the page content, not the extension, so chrome.extension.getURL is not available. You need to do the getURL call in the extension, before adding the script tag to the page.

Think of it this way: forget that you added the tag. If the page had the script reference coming from the origin server, how would it know that chrome is there to call getURL? It can't. It would need to know the full extension URL (the output of getURL). So make your script look like that.